# Настройка Java EE Создание классов сущностей

Tags: java

У меня есть БД с несколькими таблицами. После того как создал классы для каждой таблицы и покрыл аннотациями компилятор ругается на названия таблиц в аннотациях.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "articles")//ругается
@XmlRootElement
public class Articles implements Serializable {
```

и так для всех классов. Так же подсвечены все названия колонок таблиц.

Компилятор пишет "this inspection controls whether the persistence ORM annotations are checked against configured datasourse"

это файл настроек

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="myblogPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/myblog</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINEST"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

проект собирается в IDEA, БД подключена и связь с ней есть.

Answer (score 2):

вопрос решил, нужно было так же дополнительно назначить связь с таблицей из БД через alt+enter - Configure data sources